# simplify IF statement with multiple OR || conditions for the same variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Here's my code

```
var something = "four";

if(
    something == "one" || 
    something == "two" || 
    something == "three" ||
    something == "five" ||
    something == "six" ||
    something == "seven"
){
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>yes</h1>";
}else{
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>no</h1>";
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the IF statement given that all the conditions regard the same variable?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2onn6Lc2/2)**

Comment: See also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: N.B.: Although your question may belong on Code Review, **please do not repost it**. If it belongs there instead of here, it will be migrated by a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var something = 4;

if([1,2,3,5,6,7].indexOf(something) > -1) {
 document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>yes</h1>";
} else {
 document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>no</h1>";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2onn6Lc2/1/

Also, please post this type of question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: isn't better to use [1,2,3,5,6,7].includes(something) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could always invert your check:

```
var something = 4;

if(
    something < 1 || 
    something == 4 || 
    something >7
){
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>no</h1>";
}else{
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>yes</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let something = "four";

if ( ["one","two","three","five","six","seven"].includes(something) ) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>yes</h1>";
} else {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>no</h1>";
}
```